# Casting object type to another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

does anyone know how to convert the tap object in typescript so that the values ​​are also converted? e.g.

```
 interface A
{
  data:string
}
interface B
{
  data:number
}

const one:A = {data:"1"};
const two:B = one as B
```

and at this point the data element in object two is still a string. Is it possible to do some validation and convert this data?

```
const one:A = {data:"1"};
const two:B = one as B

typeof B.data !=number
```

Comment: "Casting" is not a thing in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript types only exist at compile time, so if you removed the types from:

```
interface A { data: string }
interface B { data: number }

const one: A = { data: "1" };
const two: B = one as B;
```

Then you end up with:

```
const one = { data:"1" };
const two = one;
```

Which doesn't do anything to the `data` property of `one` at all.

Types only document what you are allowed to do with your values, and they never *ever* change your values.

---

So you just write the code to do it.

```
interface A { data: string }
interface B { data: number }

const one: A = { data: "1" };
const two: B = { data: Number(one.data) };
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7ICZzHALmQGcwpQBzZAXwChRJZEUAhTHPQ5EAVwFsARtBq1aCAPYhSySRCLoAvO1z4iAIgCMamgG4xk6WADu4omyVYVXAHL8hUABSyAdFYCUNIA)